# Jquery get multiple css background-image url

Tags: jquery, css, url, background, background-image

First i've got this css-code:

```
background-image: url(/style_elements/img/first.png), url(/style_elements/img/second.png);
```

and i want to select the second background-image url with jQuery:

```
var item_img_url = item_img_url_raw.replace('url("', '').replace('")', '');
```

But this select just the first bg-img url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var item_img_url_raw = "background-image: url(/style_elements/img/first.png), url(/style_elements/img/second.png)";
var item_img_url = item_img_url_raw.split(",");
var item2 = item_img_url[1];`
```